# Rspec - API test - Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test my API

The controller I'm testing is under api > v1 > controller.rb

and the following is the rspec test code I use

```
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "test1@test.com") }

  describe "with valid token", validToken: true do
    before(:each) { authWithUser(user) }

describe "POST #create" do
  before(:each) { post :create, {test: "test data" } 

  it "returns the information for one model" do
    expect(json).to have_key('info')
  end

end
```

end

I got this error

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `request=' for #<Model:0x000000070e9988>
```

Comment: Does this work if you add `type: controller` to the outer describe block?

Comment: @zetetic I tried it and it didn't work too.